# Android dialog custom style

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes

I have a custom theme which is applied to the activity:

```
<style name="Sample" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Sample.Dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Sample.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/sample_background</item>
</style>
```

I'm creating a sample Dialog like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SampleActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);
dialog.show();
```

My custom dialog style isn't applied. Created dialog still has the standard background. What's wrong here?

Comment: if it doesn't work.. alternatively you can use an activity with dialog theme, it will actually popup as a dialog box.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it but it still doesn't explain why the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

On initializing :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SampleActivity.this, R.style.Sample.Dialog);
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The goal is to find a theme-only solution, without hardcoding anything.

Comment: It answers exactly the question you've asked.