# Add custom style in Android Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-styles, android-dialog

I created my custom Dialog class in kotlin. Everything working perfect but right now ,I try to add my custom style. Here is a my style's code

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_15</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_blue</item>

</style>
```

and there is my my kotlin code

```
class LoadingProgress(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {

    private var imageView: ImageView? = null
    private var message: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setCancelable(false)
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        setContentView(R.layout.sp_loading_dialog)
        imageView = findViewById<View>(R.id.loading_image_view) as ImageView?
        message = findViewById<View>(R.id.loading_message) as TextView?

    }

    override fun show() {
        super.show()
        (imageView!!.background as AnimationDrawable).start()

    }
}
```

In java, I know how to add custom style,but I can't rewrite java code in kotlin.

Here is a my java code'snippet:

```
public LoadingProgress(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
}
```

How I can solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android dialog custom style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332928/android-dialog-custom-style)

Comment: As you can see , I try to find solution in Kotlin. In java, I know how to solve this issue  @Sergey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change calling constructor of `Dialog`:

```
class LoadingProgress(context: Context) : Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme) { ... }
```